# Creating a label that counts up over time, iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, count, grand-central-dispatch, nstimer

I am trying to create a label (or any UI element) that starts at one number and counts up while not slowing down all other processes.

I am not exactly sure how to use Multithreading/GCD/NSTimer is best to make this work with iOS. Any suggestions? Here is the code I currently have:

```
    -(void)countup:(UIBarButtonItem *)label from:(int)startNumber to:(int)endNumber{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //         double timeInterval = 5; //5 seconds from start to stop
    //         int diff = endNumber - startNumber;
    //         double t = timeInterval/diff;
             [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 0.01];

             if(diff==0){
                 return;
             }
             if(diff>0){
                 label.title= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startNumber + 1];
                 [self countup:label from:startNumber+1 to:endNumber];
             }
             if(diff<0){
                 label.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startNumber - 1];
                 [self countup:label from:startNumber-1 to:endNumber];
             }
        });
    }
```

Unfortunately this just takes me from the first number I have, waits a while and then gets me to the last number I have.

```
I've also tried the following with little luck: 

-(void)countup:(UIBarButtonItem *)label from:(int)startNumber to:(int)endNumber{
//         double timeInterval = 5; //5 seconds from start to stop
         int diff = endNumber - startNumber;
//         double t = timeInterval/diff;

         if(diff==0){
             return;
         }
         if(diff>0){
             label.title= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startNumber + 1];
             [self countup:label from:startNumber+1 to:endNumber];
             [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                            target:self
                                            selector:@selector(callCountUp:)
                                            userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:label,
                                                      @"value1", startNumber, @"value2", endNumber, @"value3",nil]
                                            repeats:YES];
         }
         if(diff<0){
             label.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startNumber - 1];
             [self countup:label from:startNumber-1 to:endNumber];
         }
}

- (void)callCountUp:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    UIBarButtonItem *value1 = [[theTimer userInfo] objectForKey:@"value1"];
    int value2 = (int)[[theTimer userInfo] objectForKey:@"value2"];
    int value3 = (int)[[theTimer userInfo] objectForKey:@"value3"];
    [self countup: value1 from:value2 to:value3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must update UI elements that are displayed on screen in main thread, so every line where you change labels text must be wrapped in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue){
    // change labels text
}
```

And there is better way of doing what you want you should check out NSTimer, for example you could do this

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateTime)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

This would call updateTime function every second until you would stop it

Comment: I'm having trouble passing multiple arguments (basically a recursive function) into NSTimer, how would I do this?

Comment: @John you can check out how to pass multiple arguments in selectors or try the first approach

Comment: first approach = not enough arguments? could you give me an example of the code?

Comment: I tried the following but have an erorr: if(diff>0){
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue){
                 label.title= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startNumber + 1];
             }
             [self countup:label from:startNumber+1 to:endNumber];
         }

Comment: @John my bad, I put "global" instaed of "main" there, check it out and try it, my bad

Comment: This behaves really strangely, although it works for counting in very long increments, at shorter increments it jumps right away to end value. For example, if I do 100-200 and have a 1 seocnd interval, it counts up normally. It I have a half second interval, it jumps right away to 200.

Comment: @John which option behaves like that? The one with main queue dispatch or the one with nstimer? If you didnt try the one with main queue, try it please.

Answer (score 0):

The following code ended up working for me:

```
-(void)countup:(UIBarButtonItem *)label from:(int)startNumber to:(int)endNumber{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        double diff = endNumber - startNumber;
        double t = 5;
        t = t/((diff*diff)+5);
        if(t<0){
            t=t*-1;
        }
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: t];

        if(diff==0){
            return;
        }
        if(diff>0){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
                label.title= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startNumber + 1];
                [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
            });
            [self countup:label from:startNumber+1 to:endNumber];
        }
        if(diff<0){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                label.title= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startNumber - 1];
            });
            [self countup:label from:startNumber-1 to:endNumber];
        }
    });
}
```